# How to count unique non-null values in pandas dataframe using group by?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble trying to figure this out, and would really appreciate some help. So, I have a dataframe with year, state code, var1 and var2 (which contain null and non null values). I want to create a new dataframe that counts the number of unique states with at least 1 non null value and the total number of non null values grouped by year.

What my current df looks like:

```
    year    state   var1    var2    
0   2018    1       NaN     2    
1   2018    2       1       1    
2   2018    3       NaN     NaN  
3   2018    4       1       2    
4   2018    5       NaN     1   
6   2019    1       NaN     NaN  
7   2019    2       1       1    
8   2019    3       NaN     NaN  
9   2019    4       2       1    
10  2019    5       2       NaN
```

What I want the new df to look like. I want the original df transposed so that the year is the column value and my variables with the conditions are my rows.

```
                                                  2018    2019
var1
      Number of states with at least 1 non-null:  2       3
      Number of respondents with non-null var:    2       3
      Average                                     1       1
var2
      Number of states with at least 1 non-null:  2       2
      Number of respondents with non-null var:    4       2
      Average                                     2       1
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks for looking!

Comment: why would number of states with at least 1 non-null be 2 for var2, 2018? For var2 in 2018, I see 4 distinct states: 1,2,4,5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the data in the example: as stated, that data has only one row for each `(state, year)`, which defeats the point of making a difference between "states with at least 1 non null value" and "total number of non-null values".

One way I can think of that would produce the expected result is if the sample data was:

```py
nan = float('nan')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019],
    'state': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    #                  ^  ^ changed from OP's data
    'var1': [nan, 1.0, nan, 1.0, nan, nan, 1.0, nan, 2.0, 2.0],
    'var2': [2.0, 1.0, nan, 2.0, 1.0, nan, 1.0, nan, 1.0, nan],
})
```

In that case, we can get the expected result with the following:

```py
c = df.groupby(['year', 'state']).count()
res = (
    pd.concat([c/c, c], keys=['uniq', 'cnt'], axis=1)
    .groupby('year').sum(0).astype(int).T
    .swaplevel().sort_index(ascending=[True, False])
)
>>> res
year       2018  2019
var1 uniq     2     3
     cnt      2     3
var2 uniq     2     2
     cnt      4     2
```

Alternatively (and a bit less hacky):

```py
import numpy as np

c = df.groupby(['year', 'state']).count()
res = c.groupby('year').agg([np.count_nonzero, sum]).T
res.index = res.index.set_levels(['uniq', 'cnt'], level=1)
```

**Addendum**: adding an 'avg' column

```py
z = res.swaplevel().T
res = pd.concat([
    z,
    pd.concat([z['uniq'] / z['cnt']], keys=['avg'], axis=1),
], axis=1).T.swaplevel().sort_index()

>>> res
year       2018  2019
var1 avg    1.0   1.0
     cnt    2.0   3.0
     uniq   2.0   3.0
var2 avg    0.5   1.0
     cnt    4.0   2.0
     uniq   2.0   2.0
```

Comment: Hi @Pierre D, thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Also, if I wanted to add and additional row called `avg` which divides  `cnt` by  `uniq`, how could I go about doing that? I made a change to my original question and the final desired output in case this don't make sense.

Comment: sure, see "addendum".